# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in

Tags: magento-1.9

I cant put in the hole code because of the length. After move magento site get this error and all is the same as provise set up.

```
    <?php } // Orange skin
elseif(themeOptions('skin') == 5) { ?>

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['button_color_bg']); ?>              { background-color: #eb5726; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['button_hover_bg']); ?>          { background-color: #802a08; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['menu_bg']); ?>          { background-color: #FFFFFF; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['button_color_text']); ?>          { color: #802a08; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['button_color_border']); ?>          { border-color: #eb5726; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['firstmenu_bg']); ?>              { background-color: #e04920; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['secondmenu_bg']); ?>              { background-color: #e0572d; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['headermenu_bg']); ?>              { background-color: #401608; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['menu_links_color']); ?>              { color: #000000; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['footer_bg']); ?>              { background-color: #241104; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['footer_link_color']); ?>              { color: #A3A8A9; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['product_border_color']); ?>          { border-color: #EB5726; }
<?php } // Red skin
elseif(themeOptions('skin') == 6) { ?>

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['button_color_bg']); ?>              { background-color: #ff0022; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['button_hover_bg']); ?>          { background-color: #800917; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['menu_bg']); ?>          { background-color: #FFFFFF; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['button_color_text']); ?>          { color: #800917; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['button_color_border']); ?>          { border-color: #de2f43; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['firstmenu_bg']); ?>              { background-color: #de2121; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['secondmenu_bg']); ?>              { background-color: #de2f43; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['headermenu_bg']); ?>              { background-color: #941e1e; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['menu_links_color']); ?>              { color: #000000; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['footer_bg']); ?>              { background-color: #241104; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['footer_link_color']); ?>              { color: #A3A8A9; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['product_border_color']); ?>          { border-color: #800917; }

<?php } // Cyan skin
elseif(themeOptions('skin') == 7) { ?>

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['button_color_bg']); ?>              { background-color: #4ca697; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['button_hover_bg']); ?>          { background-color: #106151; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['menu_bg']); ?>          { background-color: #FFFFFF; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['button_color_text']); ?>          { color: #106151; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['button_color_border']); ?>          { border-color: #4ca697; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['firstmenu_bg']); ?>              { background-color: #1dab8f; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['secondmenu_bg']); ?>              { background-color: #26aba2; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['headermenu_bg']); ?>              { background-color: #08403a; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['menu_links_color']); ?>              { color: #ffffff; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['footer_bg']); ?>              { background-color: #241104; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['footer_link_color']); ?>              { color: #A3A8A9; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['product_border_color']); ?>          { border-color: #4ca697; }
<?php } // Pastel skin

elseif(themeOptions('skin') == 8) { ?>

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['button_color_bg']); ?>              { background-color: #d6d3d2; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['button_hover_bg']); ?>          { background-color: #75716f; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['menu_bg']); ?>          { background-color: #FFFFFF; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['button_color_text']); ?>          { color: #b5b5b5; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['button_color_border']); ?>          { border-color: #d6d3d2; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['firstmenu_bg']); ?>              { background-color: #707070; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['secondmenu_bg']); ?>              { background-color: #474747; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['headermenu_bg']); ?>              { background-color: #212121; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['menu_links_color']); ?>              { color: #ffffff; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['footer_bg']); ?>              { background-color: #241104; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['footer_link_color']); ?>              { color: #A3A8A9; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['product_border_color']); ?>          { border-color: #e0e0e0; }
<?php }
else {
?> 
    <?php echo jsString($selectors['button_color_bg']); ?>              { background-color: #<?php echo themeOptions('button_color') ?>; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['button_hover_bg']); ?>          { background-color: #<?php echo themeOptions('button_hover') ?>; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['menu_bg']); ?>          { background-color: #<?php echo themeOptions('menu_bg') ?>; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['button_color_text']); ?>          { color: #<?php echo themeOptions('button_color') ?>; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['button_color_border']); ?>          { border-color: #<?php echo themeOptions('button_color') ?>; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['firstmenu_bg']); ?>              { background-color: #<?php echo themeOptions('firstmenu_bg') ?>; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['secondmenu_bg']); ?>              { background-color: #<?php echo themeOptions('secondmenu_bg') ?>; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['headermenu_bg']); ?>              { background-color: #<?php echo themeOptions('headermenu_bg') ?>; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['menu_links_color']); ?>              { color: #<?php echo themeOptions('menu_links_color') ?>; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['footer_bg']); ?>              { background-color: #<?php echo themeOptions('footer_bg') ?>; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['footer_link_color']); ?>              { color: #<?php echo themeOptions('footer_link_color') ?>; }

    <?php echo jsString($selectors['product_border_color']); ?>          { border-color: #<?php echo themeOptions('product_border_color') ?>; }

<? } ?>
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
<?php if(themeOptions('floattopmenu')): ?>
window.onload = function() {
        skrollr.init({
            forceHeight: false
        });
    }
<?php endif; ?>
var tpj=jQuery;
tpj.noConflict();

tpj(document).ready(function() {

if (tpj.fn.cssOriginal!=undefined)
    tpj.fn.css = tpj.fn.cssOriginal;

    tpj('.fullwidthbanner').revolution(
        {
            delay:<?php echo themeOptions('delay') ?>,
            startwidth:980,
            startheight:480,

            onHoverStop:"on",                       // Stop Banner Timet at Hover on Slide on/off

            thumbWidth:100,                         // Thumb With and Height and Amount (only if navigation Tyope set to thumb !)
            thumbHeight:50,
            thumbAmount:3,

            hideThumbs:0,
            navigationType:"bullet",                // bullet, thumb, none
            navigationArrows:"solo",                // nexttobullets, solo (old name verticalcentered), none

            navigationStyle:"round",                // round,square,navbar,round-old,square-old,navbar-old, or any from the list in the docu (choose between 50+ different item), custom


            navigationHAlign:"center",              // Vertical Align top,center,bottom
            navigationVAlign:"bottom",                  // Horizontal Align left,center,right
            navigationHOffset:0,
            navigationVOffset:20,

            soloArrowLeftHalign:"left",
            soloArrowLeftValign:"center",
            soloArrowLeftHOffset:20,
            soloArrowLeftVOffset:0,

            soloArrowRightHalign:"right",
            soloArrowRightValign:"center",
            soloArrowRightHOffset:20,
            soloArrowRightVOffset:0,

            touchenabled:"on",                      // Enable Swipe Function : on/off


            stopAtSlide:<?php echo themeOptions('autoplay') ?>,         // Stop Timer if Slide "x" has been Reached. If stopAfterLoops set to 0, then it stops already in the first Loop at slide X which defined. -1 means do not stop at any slide. stopAfterLoops has no sinn in this case.
            stopAfterLoops:0,                       // Stop Timer if All slides has been played "x" times. IT will stop at THe slide which is defined via stopAtSlide:x, if set to -1 slide never stop automatic

            hideCaptionAtLimit:0,                   // It Defines if a caption should be shown under a Screen Resolution ( Basod on The Width of Browser)
            hideAllCaptionAtLilmit:0,               // Hide all The Captions if Width of Browser is less then this value
            hideSliderAtLimit:0,                    // Hide the whole slider, and stop also functions if Width of Browser is less than this value


            fullWidth:"on",

            shadow:0                                //0 = no Shadow, 1,2,3 = 3 Different Art of Shadows -  (No Shadow in Fullwidth Version !)

        });




});
</script>



<script type="text/javascript"><!--

jQuery(document).ready(function() {


      // Move search to menu

      jQuery('.form-search button.button').insertBefore('.form-search input.input-text').show();
      jQuery('.top-bar').insertBefore('#nav').show();



      // Show blog posts in News
     // $('.shop-about-news ul').html($('#awbloglatest').html());      


      // Blocks sliders
      jQuery('.shop-about-news .bxslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'vertical',
        pager: false
      });

      jQuery('.shop-about-slider .bxslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'horizontal',
        auto: true,
        controls: false
      });

        jQuery(function(){        
        jQuery(".widget_facebook_right").hover(function(){            
        jQuery(".widget_facebook_right").stop(true, false).animate({right: "0" }, 800, 'easeOutQuint' );        
        },
  function(){            
        jQuery(".widget_facebook_right").stop(true, false).animate({right: "-245" }, 800, 'easeInQuint' );        
        },1000);    
  });


      jQuery(function(){        
        jQuery(".widget_custom_box_left").hover(function(){            
        jQuery(".widget_custom_box_left").stop(true, false).animate({left: "0" }, 800, 'easeOutQuint' );        
        },
  function(){            
        jQuery(".widget_custom_box_left").stop(true, false).animate({left: "-245" }, 800, 'easeInQuint' );        
        },1000);    
  });


      // Image animation
      jQuery(".fade-image").live({
        mouseenter:
           function()
           {
                jQuery(this).stop().fadeTo(300, 0.6);
           },
        mouseleave:
           function()
           {
                jQuery(this).stop().fadeTo(300, 1);
           }
       }
    );


    jQuery('#header_menu select, .pager select').selectbox();



    jQuery(".show-more-button").live('click', function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        var i = 0;

        var parent_container = jQuery(this).parent();


        parent_container.find(jQuery('.hidethisblock .box-product-item')).each(function(){
          if(i < <?php echo themeOptions('new_carousel_limit'); ?>) {
            jQuery(this).hide().appendTo(parent_container.find(jQuery('.more-module'))).slideDown();

          }
          i++;

        });


        jQuery('html, body').delay(500).animate({
            scrollTop: parent_container.find(jQuery('.more-module .box-product-item')).last().offset().top

        }, 500);



        if(parent_container.find(jQuery('.hidethisblock .box-product-item')).length == 0) {
          jQuery(this).fadeOut();
        }

    });




});

<?php echo themeOptions('customjs'); ?>

--></script>

<style>


    body{
        background-color:#<?php echo themeOptions('maincolor') ?>;
        background-attachment: <?php echo themeOptions('bg_attachment') ?>;
        background-position: <?php echo themeOptions('bg_position_y') ?> <?php echo themeOptions('bg_position_x') ?>;
        background-repeat: <?php echo themeOptions('bg_repeat') ?>;
    }  

    <?php if(themeOptions('googlefont')!='Arial'): ?>
    body {
        font-family: <?php 
          $googlefont_name = explode(":", themeOptions('googlefont'));
          $googlefont_name = $googlefont_name[0];

          echo $googlefont_name;
         ?>;
    }
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(themeOptions('fullwidthslider')):
    ?>
    .fullwidthbanner-container {
        width:100%;
    }
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(themeOptions('hide_wish')): ?>

        .buttons-wish, #header_menu .links li:nth-child(2) {
            display:none!important;
        }
        .buttons-compare {
            margin-left:13px;
        }

    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if(themeOptions('hide_compare')): ?>

        .buttons-compare {
            display:none!important;
        }

    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(themeOptions('hide_cart')): ?>

        .buttons-cart, .minicart-wrapper, .top-link-cart-li, .quanitybox, #header_menu .links li:nth-child(4) a {
            display:none!important;
        }
        .product-buttons .product-buttons-row:nth-child(1){
            display:none;
        }
    <?php endif; ?>


    <?php if(themeOptions('hide_rightblock')): ?>

        .product-view .product-shop .product_right {
            display:none;
        }
        .product-view .product-shop .white-back {
            margin-right: 0;
            width: 450px;
        }

    <?php endif; ?>


    <?php echo themeOptions('customcss'); ?>

</style>

<?php if(themeOptions('pattern') && themeOptions('pattern') != ''): ?>
    <style>
        body{ background-image: url(<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'wysiwyg/simplegreat/'.themeOptions('pattern') ?>); }    
    </style>
<?php endif; ?>
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/ie7.css'); ?>" media="screen"/>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/ie9.css'); ?>" media="screen"/>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code contains one short PHP open tag (`<?`), I think that's the cause. You should replace it with a normal open tag (`<?php`) or enable PHP short open tags (in your `php.ini` file change `short_open_tag = Off` to `short_open_tag = On`).